# Simple calculator app in Android studio keeps closing

Tags: java, android, xml, logcat

So I have been trying to run a simple calculator app on android studio, but it keeps crashing. I´ve checked the logcat, and all the files and still can´t for the life of me figure out what´s wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.
I could add the logcat over here as well if that would help!
This is my XML code:

My java code:

```
public class Assignment_01 extends Activity {

    private Button btnGo;
    private EditText checkAmount, numOfPeople;
    private double tip = 0.15;
    double checkAmountD, checkAmountR;
    double numPeopleD;
    private TextView viewBill, viewPerson, viewTip;
    double totalB, totalP, totalTP, totalT;

    /** hi */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_linearlayout);

        // get info from text box called checkAmount:

        checkAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.checkAmount);
        String checkString = checkAmount.getText().toString();
        checkAmountD = Double.parseDouble(checkString);
        checkAmountR = Math.round(checkAmountD * 100.0) / 100.0;

        // get info from number of people

        numOfPeople = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numOfPeople);
        String numPeopleS = numOfPeople.getText().toString();
        numPeopleD = Double.parseDouble(numPeopleS);

        // if button is clicked, calculate other 4 values and display them

        // button called btnLogin:

        btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
        btnGo.setOnClickListener(  new View.OnClickListener() { // view. ? maybe not

            // once button is clicked (onClick)
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // calculate total tip, total bill, total per person, and total tip per person
                totalT = checkAmountR  * tip;
                totalB = checkAmountR + totalT;
                totalP = totalB / numPeopleD;
                totalTP = totalT / numPeopleD;

                // print these 4 out on the edit texts
                setNewText();

            } // on click
        });   // on click listener

    }

    public void setNewText(){
        // print these 4 out on the edit texts
        TextView viewBill = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalBill);
        String totalBillS = String.valueOf(totalB);
        viewBill.setText("$" + totalBillS);
        viewBill.append("$" + totalBillS);

        TextView viewPerson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalPerPerson);
        String totalPerPS = String.valueOf(totalP);
        viewPerson.setText("$" + totalPerPS);
        viewPerson.append("$" + totalPerPS);

        TextView viewTip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTip);
        String totalTipS = String.valueOf(totalP);
        viewTip.setText("$" + totalTipS);
        viewTip.append("$" + totalTipS);

        TextView viewTipPerPerson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipPerPerson);
        String tipPerPersonS = String.valueOf(totalTP);
        viewTipPerPerson.setText("$" + tipPerPersonS);
        viewTipPerPerson.append("$" + tipPerPersonS);
    }
}
```

stack overflow is not letting me add the XML code or the android manifest

Thank you in advance!

This is the first half of the logcat:

```
2021-02-18 00:27:56.993 3622-3622/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.course.example, PID: 3622
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.course.example/com.course.example.LayoutDemo}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at com.course.example.LayoutDemo.onCreate(LayoutDemo.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2021-02-18 00:27:57.303 2605-3513/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for instantapp-dev-manager
2021-02-18 00:27:57.578 1988-2101/system_process E/SupplicantStaIfaceHal: ISupplicantStaIface.setPowerSave failed: {.code = FAILURE_UNKNOWN, .debugMessage = }
2021-02-18 00:27:57.601 1728-1953/? E/Netd: no such netId 101
2021-02-18 00:27:57.602 1988-2104/system_process E/ConnectivityService: Exception adding interface: java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Machine is not on the network (code 64)
2021-02-18 00:27:57.602 1728-1953/? E/Netd: no such netId 101
2021-02-18 00:27:57.638 2605-3811/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2021-02-18 00:27:57.676 1988-2101/system_process E/SupplicantStaIfaceHal: ISupplicantStaIface.setPowerSave failed: {.code = FAILURE_UNKNOWN, .debugMessage = }
2021-02-18 00:27:57.679 1728-2197/? E/Netd: no such netId 101
2021-02-18 00:27:57.679 1988-2104/system_process E/ConnectivityService: Exception in addRoute for non-gateway: java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Machine is not on the network (code 64)
2021-02-18 00:27:57.679 1728-2197/? E/Netd: no such netId 101
```

Comment: `I could add the logcat over here as well if that would help` without logs, we'd be guessing how to fix the problem, so yes, you _always_ need to add logs. those are the first things you should be looking at when there's a problem

Comment: @a_local_nobody okay, would you recommend filtering it with anything specific? it´s quite long atm

Comment: you need to find the error logs _for your app_, because those are your crashes, so yes, filter in logcat for error and for the selected application

Comment: @a_local_nobody yep okay makes sense, just did that, thank you

Comment: i've made some changes to the stack trace you've posted, usually you should look for `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:` or something like this, that's how you'll know where it begins. in your case it's saying : `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String`. now, if you've known about stack traces and reading them, you might have guessed what was wrong in your code, right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are assigning values to `checkAmountR`, `checkAmountD`, `numPeopleD` in `onCreate()` which will be assigned with empty `String` initially, so when you parse it throws `NumberFormatException`

move those inside `onClick()`, so when clicked it will actually get the value from `EditText`

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_linearlayout);
        checkAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.checkAmount);
        numOfPeople = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numOfPeople);
        btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
        btnGo.setOnClickListener(  new View.OnClickListener() { // view. ? maybe 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String checkString = checkAmount.getText().toString();
                checkAmountD = Double.parseDouble(checkString);
                checkAmountR = Math.round(checkAmountD * 100.0) / 100.0;
               
                String numPeopleS = numOfPeople.getText().toString();
                numPeopleD = Double.parseDouble(numPeopleS);

                totalT = checkAmountR  * tip;
                totalB = checkAmountR + totalT;
                totalP = totalB / numPeopleD;
                totalTP = totalT / numPeopleD;

                // print these 4 out on the edit texts
                setNewText();

            } // on click
        });   // on click listener

    }
```

Also, always use `tryParse`, to avoid this kind of `NumberFormatException`